# (Fixed) Why the liquid is not transparent through glass?

Tags: lighting

I made a glass of drink, with a straw, ice cubes and bubbles. Why the liquid is not transparent through glass?
I am not sure which step I messed up, here is the blender file. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: The simple answer: because you are using _Eevee_ and it's not very good at it. For a better answer an _Eevee_ expert might be able to help you. I would always use _Cycles_ for this kind of scene. By the way, setting the _Transmission_ to 2 instead of the maximum value of 1 will not make a difference.

Comment: I did not say that it is already perfectly set up for the use with _Cycles_ ;) I suspect you have duplicated the inner faces of the glass to make the liquid. That's why the normals are flipped on the liquid, the inside pointing outwards which makes it look more mirror-like - so it is showing at the bottom, you just see the reflection of the environment there. Go into _Edit Mode_, select all with `A` then `Shift`+`N` to recalculate the normals and it will look immediately much better. More bounces would help, too: [settings comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQdn9.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eevee, you can't see an object with *Screen Space Refraction* behind another with *Screen Space Refraction*, you need to switch to Cycles or change the material of the glass, for example mix it with a *Transparent* node through a *Mix Shader* with an *Input > Layer Weight* as factor (and select *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* instead of *Opaque*):

[image]

As for your liquid, the normals are inverted, therefore this bad deformation, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: https://imgur.com/MhGkJw8
It didn't work for eevee

Comment: have you selected Alpha Blend instead of Opaque for the glass?

Comment: https://imgur.com/GDlN4lL
At Eevee, it worked, thank you.
https://imgur.com/coDd1Gl
But at cycles, the lower bottom of liquid doesn't show.

Comment: Oh Ok I've found your problem, the normals of your liquid are inverted, select all in Edit mode and press Shift N

Comment: The problem is fixed, thanks a lot!
https://imgur.com/a/qaRqv4V

Comment: You're welcome.............;  ;)  nice result by the way!